# How to make MFA based on user device?

Tags: python, fastapi, fingerprint, multi-factor-authentication

I'm going to make an application intended to work with users. I would like to include a functionality responsible for performing multi-factor authentication based on user devices.

So the idea is following:
When a user have registered, they will receive an email message or an SMS with token. The device from which they were registering is saved in database so they will be able to sign in without any additional verification in order to check their identity. When when an attempt to login from another device is occurred, we need to perform MFA again and send a token, and if the attempt is successful, we save the new device. Actually, I would like to make something similar to mechanism used in Google, but without windows with two-digit numbers.

I'd like to use some kind of unique identifier for each device, which would allow me to avoid situations in which a browser and location are different and the system perceives this as different devices.

I also found out that fingerprint technology is used for this. Is it so?

In your answer I would like you to explain best options to implement this task. I would like the question to be considered in the context of backend development.
Please try to paint the sequence of actions in all details. This will help me a lot.

P.S.: I don't speak English very well, so if you see mistakes, please don't judge and correct them if it makes my question clearer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `When when an attempt to login from another device is occurred, we need to perform MFA again and send a token` - this is exactly what a _regular_ login is - you take the user/password + 2fa and give the user a token instead; this token can then be re-used later (i.e. what's called a session token, another variant is the "remember me" token). I'm guessing you'd have two tokens in this case, one for the session itself and a second token to perform logins? That would put in the same bin as a "fresh token" which is used by many auth systems - a token to retrieve new tokens.